# Orden de compra en blanco Odoo13

Tags: odoo

Estoy implementando Odoo para gestionar compras.
Cuando genero una orden de compra, al abrir documento pdf se muestra en blanco.
Acá unas imágenes
paso 1. Acá cuando s genera el documento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

paso 2. acá llega al correo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

paso 3. al abrir docuemnto (está en blanco)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar con este problema.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `wkhtmltopdf` tienes instalada? En caso de no estar instalado, el proceso de instalación varia en función del sistema operativo o distribución. [Proceso de instalación en Ubuntu 16.04/18.04](https://gist.github.com/srmds/2507aa3bcdb464085413c650fe42e31d)

Comment: uuff,, lo ignoro @daniel-luque. Tengo Odoo en windows